# Does Flash CS3 export SVG's?

Tags: flash, flash-cs5, flash-cs4, flash-cs3

The only reason I use flash is for vector editing.  I do not like what Adobe has done to the drawing tools in CC.  No longer can I drag shapes and the anchor point be on the outside automatically.  Also it always makes shape objects, I prefer just the shapes.  I also need to export to SVG (which is fine in CC).  I need to revert to an old version of flash, but before I buy one off Amazon, I need to know for sure that I can export to SVG from Flash.  Which is the earliest version of Flash that will export to SVG?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the Flash editor in a long time and can't remember.
You may have better luck asking on superuser or on the [GraphicDesign stackexchange](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/)

Since this is a programming oriented site, here's a code solution:
Would using the [as3swf](https://github.com/claus/as3swf) library to [extract shapes as SVG](https://github.com/claus/as3swf/wiki/Shape-Export) from an exported swf file (even early versions)

You can find a very basic as3swf based svg exporter I wrote about 4 years ago [here](http://wonderfl.net/c/sPjI).

Comment: Your awesome, now I can keep using Flash 8, the best version of Flash ever!

Comment: If my answer was helpful, feel free to vote/mark as you see fit ;) thank you

Comment: Well it doesn't answer the original question.  And I don't have enough rep to upvote.